# Stylish CSS One Page Website

Tags: css, web, stylish, userstyles

Is there a way I can change the CSS for individual tabs in a one-page website? I like to use the 'Stylish' extension in the chrome web store to change the way certain websites look my modifying their CS but keep in mind that I am very inexperienced in this and am still learning.

So basically what's happening is there's some text in the middle of the page that interferes with the location of the buttons and I have tried hiding it by:

```
p {
    margin: 0 0 -29px;
}
```

and

```
p {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

But as the website only uses tabs to display content and does not have any other links, changing this will also change what's in the other tabs. So if I hide p in one tab the other tabs are affected as well and I only want that tab to have p hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every tab has an `id` or a `class`, you should first refer to them like below:

```
// For id

    #tab-id p {visibility: hidden;}

// For class

    .tab-class p {visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: Well, not every, to be honest... In case when no unique id or class is available, [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudoclass can help.

Comment: Yes you're right but that specific page has it (links are deleted).